# Making this f.autocomplete_field and this Tag model work together?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Post model and a Tag model (the later has an attribute called `:name`).
The Post model has an `attr_accessor` called `:tag_name` that I added in order to make
[rails3-jquery-autocomplete](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete) plugin work:

**post.rb:**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :content, :tag_name

  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags

  def tag!(tags)
    tags = tags.split(" ").map do |tag|
      Tag.find_or_create_by_name(tag)
    end
    self.tags << tags
  end
end
```

**tag.rb:**

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
end
```

**posts_controller.rb:**

```
  def create
    @user = current_user
    @post = @user.posts.new(params[:post])

    if @post.save
      redirect_to @post, notice: 'post was successfully created.'
    else
      render action: "new"
    end

    @post.tag!(params[:tags])
  end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= f.autocomplete_field :tag_name, autocomplete_tag_name_posts_path, :"data-delimiter" => ' ' %>
```

With the code above the auto-completion is working but when I submit the form I get this error: undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass.

I'm not sure what to do with `f.autocomplete_field`. Before it used to submit perfectly like this:

```
<%= text_field_tag :tags, params[:tags] %>
```

(I took this from [this](http://www.javabeat.net/articles/292-creating-tags-using-rails-1.html) tutorial)

Now, I don't know how to make the form submit successfully again and create the tags for the posts. I don't know either what should I modify in the post model's **tag! method** and controller's **create** action.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `create` action, the line -

```
@post.tag!(params[:tags])
```

is expecting `params[:tags]`. There is no such param because when you change

```
<%= text_field_tag :tags, params[:tags] %>
```

to

```
<%= f.autocomplete_field :tag_name, autocomplete_tag_name_posts_path, :"data-delimiter" => ' ' %>
```

, the params that is really holding the tags will be in **`params[:post][:tag_name]`**. This is because the html produced by the two have different name attributes for the text field. In the first case it is `tags` and in the second one it is `tag_name`.

So changing it to:

```
@post.tag!(params[:post][:tag_name])
```

should work

Comment: Thanks a lot! I always wondered what it means to put attributes like this: `params[:first_attribute][:second_attribute]` What it does (Sorry, I'm a Rails beginner)?

Comment: Welcome Alex. Within rails controllers, there is a `params` hash that contains the parameters that were submitted in a form or via the url. In forms, the `name` attribute of the input elements constitute keys of the params hash and the inputted data are becomes corresponding values. If parameters are passed in urls (using ?x=23), they too become part of the params hash.